# Rails capybara click label with link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

in my rspec feature I try to check a checkbox with it related label because the input is hidden. My label contains link (`<a>` tag), so every time I use `check('user[agree_terms]', allow_label_click: true)` it never checks the box but instead open the link contains in the label.

Here's my view generated from `ERB`

```html
    <p class="col boolean required user_agree_terms">
      <input name="user[agree_terms]" type="hidden" value="0">
      <input class="boolean required" required="required" aria-required="true" type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[agree_terms]" id="user_agree_terms">
      <label class="boolean required" for="user_agree_terms">
        <abbr title="required">*</abbr>
        J'ai accepté les <a target="_blank" href="https://somelink">Conditions Générales d'Utilisation</a> et la <a target="_blank" href="https://somelink">Politique de Confidentialité</a>
      </label>
    </p>
```

Here's my spec

```rb
  # I tried both but its behave the same way : open the <a> tag
  find('label[for="influencer_agree_terms"]').click
  check('influencer[agree_terms]', allow_label_click: true)
```

Do you know another way to check that box ?

By the way the UI on browser work correctly when I click the label.

Comment: I would rethink that html, labels are supposed to be clicked to toggle the associated input as you are trying to do in your test. If you put a link inside that you are breaking that expected flow, a user would probably see there's a link, but have you consider accessibility? maybe it doesn't work properly with a screen reader for example (what if a screen reader interacts with the page clicking the center like capybara does?). I would just move the link out of the label, you avoid problems and you can still have the same behavior and visual style with css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tell Capybara to click on an element it clicks in the middle of that element which in this case is where you have the `conditions` link, so that takes the click before the label element. One option would be to specifically click on the abbr element, which is in the label but away from the link

```
find('label[for="influencer_agree_terms"] abbr').click
```

Another option would be to take advantage of the fact that allow_label_click supports specifying offsets for the click location

```
check('influencer[agree_terms]', allow_label_click: { x: 10, y: 10 })
```

Depending on the setting of `Capybara.w3c_click_offset` that offset could be from the center or from the top left corner of the label element so adjust the values as necessary. Technically you can do the same thing when calling click

```
find('label[for="influencer_agree_terms"]').click(x: 10, y: 10)
```

but it's generally better to use `check` when dealing with a checkbox

Comment: Thank you for your answer with multiple solutions, I will try to use check as it is more meaningful 

Answer (score 0):

By default capybara `#click` method will click in the middle of the element, right where my link is located.
Fortunately `#click` has offset option as follow `#click(x: 0, y: 0)`.

So to check a box with the help of its label containing link :
`find('label[for="influencer_agree_terms"]').click(x: 0, y: 0)`